# Upgrading Telerik RAD Controls for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, rad-controls

Can someone tell me how I go about upgrading the Telerik ASP.NET controls? I am currently using the Q3 2008 release and I just recently bought the Q1 2009 SP1 release. How do I upgrade my projects? Do I need to uninstall the old one and install the new one or just install the new one? Also how do my projects get upgraded? Also, what about my projects that I have "live"? Do I just need to upload the new DLLs and and change my web.config? Any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Updating RadControls for ASP.NET to another version or license 
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/general/updating-radcontrols-for-asp-net-to-another-version-or-license.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple live sites I recommend keeping them all in the same version of Telerik RadControls. If you deploy compiled assemblies to your sites, and you compile with different version of RadControls that is found in the site's /bin or the server's GAC, you'll get an error. (At least without assembly redirects, I guess)

I have upgraded RadControls multiple times in the past year with the following process:

1. Full install of the new RadControls version in the dev machine
2. Replace Telerik.Web.UI.dll in your projects with the new version.
3. Recompile and test. There are surprises, especially in the look&feel of controls. Skins can change too, and you may have references to skins that do not exist anymore, causing an error.
4. Deploy newly compiled dlls and the Telerik.Web.UI.dll at the same time
   to production
5. Uninstall older Radcontrols version from the dev machine

I'm using Visual Studio Web Application Projects only and refer to Telerik.Web.UI.dll in the site's /bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You would have got a Release note along with the the New version. Just check for the whats new in this release and compatibility section of that document and see is there any breaking changes present in the release(You will not have any , but its good to have a look to double ensure). All you need to do is to put the latest DLL to the GAC and  change the Web.Config file, and test your application. If every thing looks , do the same thing in the Production as well. In case if you are consuming the telerik dll in the dll projects . Try adding Assembly redirect entry in the web config.

Answer (score 0):

There are also several videos on Telerik TV that show you how to manually and automatically upgrade projects that use the RadControls:

http://tv.telerik.com/search?q=upgrade

Hope that helps.